How to capture and pass Customer details in live chat
I wanted to identify customer's details like their device and their location and sent the details to the agents during a chat. Is that possible in advanced Chat - MIAW?

Yes, it is possible to capture and pass customer details like their device and location to agents during a chat in Salesforce Advanced Chat (MIAW). You can achieve this using a pre-chat script (Pre-Chat API) or by customizing the chat code to capture these details automatically.
Pre-Chat API: You can set up a pre-chat form to ask customers for this information before the conversation starts. These details can then be mapped to custom fields and sent to the agent.
Automatic Capture: To capture details like the customer’s device or location, you can use JavaScript to gather this data automatically and pass it as parameters in the chat.
For details like location, you can leverage the Geolocation API, and for device information, you can use the Navigator API to capture device type, browser, etc.
